# Cascading hadoop streaming mapreductions with binary data

Tags: python, binary-data, hadoop-streaming

I'm having trouble to figure out how to use the binary output for a hadoop streaming mapreduction as the input for another hadoop streaming mapreduction.

echo.py:

```
import sys

while True:
  buffer = sys.stdin.read(1024)
  if not buffer:
    break
  sys.stdout.write(buffer)
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

$ xxd input.txt

```
0000000: 6b31 0976 310a 6b32 0976 320a 6b33 0976  k1.v1.k2.v2.k3.v
0000010: 330a 6b34 0976 340a                      3.k4.v4.
```

With the following commands, I was expecting to get a output.seq.txt file which looks like input.txt **but that does not happen. Why?**

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /samples/output.seq ;\
./hadoop/bin/hadoop jar ./hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar \
 -D 'stream.map.input=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.map.output=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.reduce.input=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.reduce.output=typedbytes' \
 -D 'mapred.job.name=echo.py (1/2)' \
 -mapper 'python -m echo map 0 262144000' \
 -reducer 'python -m echo red 0 262144000' \
 -file echo.py \
 -inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat' \
 -input /samples/input.txt \
 -outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat' \
 -output /samples/output.seq ;\
./hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -cat /samples/output.seq/part-0000 > output.seq
```

$ xxd output.seq

```
0000000: 5345 5106 2f6f 7267 2e61 7061 6368 652e  SEQ./org.apache.
0000010: 6861 646f 6f70 2e74 7970 6564 6279 7465  hadoop.typedbyte
0000020: 732e 5479 7065 6442 7974 6573 5772 6974  s.TypedBytesWrit
0000030: 6162 6c65 2f6f 7267 2e61 7061 6368 652e  able/org.apache.
0000040: 6861 646f 6f70 2e74 7970 6564 6279 7465  hadoop.typedbyte
0000050: 732e 5479 7065 6442 7974 6573 5772 6974  s.TypedBytesWrit
0000060: 6162 6c65 0000 0000 0000 41e2 785b 996d  able......A.x[.m
0000070: f015 772c 9c66 10d4 13e7 0000 0012 0000  ..w,.f..........
0000080: 0009 0000 0005 0700 0000 0000 0000 0507  ................
0000090: 0000 0000 0000 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007  ................
00000a0: 0700 0000 026b 3100 0000 0707 0000 0002  .....k1.........
00000b0: 7631 0000 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700  v1..............
00000c0: 0000 026b 3200 0000 0707 0000 0002 7632  ...k2.........v2
00000d0: 0000 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000  ................
00000e0: 026b 3300 0000 0707 0000 0002 7633 0000  .k3.........v3..
00000f0: 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000 026b  ...............k
0000100: 3400 0000 0707 0000 0002 7634            4.........v4
```

Then

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /samples/output.seq.txt ;\
./hadoop/bin/hadoop jar ./hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar \
 -D 'stream.map.input=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.map.output=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.reduce.input=typedbytes' \
 -D 'stream.reduce.output=typedbytes' \
 -D 'mapred.job.name=echo.py (2/2)' \
 -mapper 'python -m echo map 0 262144000' \
 -reducer 'python -m echo red 0 262144000' \
 -file echo.py \
 -inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat' \
 -input /samples/output.seq/part-00000 \
 -outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat' \
 -output /samples/output.seq.txt ;\
./hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -cat /samples/output.seq.txt/part-0000 > output.seq.txt
```

$ xxd output.seq.txt

```
0000000: 5345 5106 2f6f 7267 2e61 7061 6368 652e  SEQ./org.apache.
0000010: 6861 646f 6f70 2e74 7970 6564 6279 7465  hadoop.typedbyte
0000020: 732e 5479 7065 6442 7974 6573 5772 6974  s.TypedBytesWrit
0000030: 6162 6c65 2f6f 7267 2e61 7061 6368 652e  able/org.apache.
0000040: 6861 646f 6f70 2e74 7970 6564 6279 7465  hadoop.typedbyte
0000050: 732e 5479 7065 6442 7974 6573 5772 6974  s.TypedBytesWrit
0000060: 6162 6c65 0000 0000 0000 41ef bfbd 785b  able......A...x[
0000070: efbf bd6d efbf bd15 772c efbf bd66 10ef  ...m....w,...f..
0000080: bfbd 13ef bfbd 0000 0012 0000 0009 0000  ................
0000090: 0005 0700 0000 0000 0000 0507 0000 0000  ................
00000a0: 0000 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000  ................
00000b0: 026b 3100 0000 0707 0000 0002 7631 0000  .k1.........v1..
00000c0: 0016 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000 026b  ...............k
00000d0: 3200 0000 0707 0000 0002 7632 0000 0016  2.........v2....
00000e0: 0000 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000 026b 3300  .............k3.
00000f0: 0000 0707 0000 0002 7633 0000 0016 0000  ........v3......
0000100: 000b 0000 0007 0700 0000 026b 3400 0000  ...........k4...
0000110: 0707 0000 0002 7634 0a                   ......v4.
```

(Side question: the above commands take ~30-60 to finish each. Why are them so slow!?)

Answer (score 0):

For your first job, your input looks like text, so you can skip the `-inputformat` and specifying your inputs and outputs as `typedbytes`.  You should end up with a `SequenceFile` that uses `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` for both the keys and the values.  At present, it may be double-encoding the values that Python returns.

I've been digging into this recently, so maybe [Binary Streaming with Hadoop (and Node.js)](http://mojodna.net/2013/12/27/binary-streaming-with-hadoop-and-nodejs.html) will help clear things up.